# Why is Chrome significantly different in performance than Firefox or Edge for these anagram algorithms?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, benchmarking

So I have these two separate javascript anagram algorithms. One is significantly faster in Chrome but marginally slower in Firefox and Edge. What is the major difference between the implementations that makes `isAnagram()` faster than `anagram()` in Chrome but slower in Firefox and Edge?

```
function isAnagram(word1, word2) {
    if(word1.length != word2.length){
        return false;
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < word1.length; i++){
        var letteridx = word2.indexOf(word1[i]);
        if(letteridx === -1){
            return false;
        }
        var firsthalf = word2.slice(0, letteridx);
        var secondhalf = word2.slice(letteridx + 1, word2.length);
        word2 = firsthalf + secondhalf;
    }
    if(word2.length === 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function anagram(w1, w2){
    return w1.split("").sort().join("") === w2.split("").sort().join("");
}
var words1 = ["dog", "cat","tacocat", "silent", "tacocatt", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." ];
var words2 = ["god", "bird", "tacocat", "listen", "tacocat", "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba", ".murobal tse di mina tillom tnuresed aiciffo iuq apluc ni tnus ,tnediorp non tatadipuc taceacco tnis ruetpecxE .rutairap allun taiguf ue erolod mullic esse tilev etatpulov ni tiredneherper ni rolod eruri etua siuD .tauqesnoc odommoc ae xe piuqila tu isin sirobal ocmallu noitaticrexe durtson siuq ,mainev minim da mine tU .auqila angam erolod te erobal tu tnudidicni ropmet domsuie od des ,tile gnicsipida rutetcesnoc ,tema tis rolod muspi meroL", ".murobal tse di mina tillom tnuresed aiciffo iuq apluc ni tnus ,tnediorp non tatadipuc taceacco tnis ruetpecxE .rutairap alkun taiguf ue erolod mullic esse tilev etatpulov ni tiredneherper ni rolod eruri etua siuD .tauqesnoc odommoc ae xe piuqila tu isin sirobal ocmallu noitaticrexe durtson siuq ,mainev minim da mine tU .auqila angam erolod te erobal tu tnudidicni ropmet domsuie od des ,tile gnicsipida rutetcesnoc ,tema tis rolod muspi meroL"];
var x;
```

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50npi.png):
[image]

[Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN5S2.png):
[image]

[Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZX6X.png):
[image]

Benchmarks used:

https://jsperf.com/anagramtest

http://jsben.ch/NQLvJ

Comment: Educated guess: The string operations `word2.slice() + word2.slice()` are quite slow, as the engine has to create three strings at every iteration. Maybe Chrome inlines it and just has to create one new string per iteration.

Comment: Aand your testcase is too short to be meaningful. Run them a few hundred times in a loop

Comment: Different browsers have different speeds https://www.pcworld.com/article/3213031/computers/best-web-browsers.html

Comment: Let me see if I can add some pictures to show you why it's so different. Testcases are scant, but it's also pretty drastic.

Comment: Thanks @bestinamir, was hoping to figure out exactly what is wrong here. The difference is so large I almost want to believe it's an issue with Chrome's sort() function.

Comment: If you doing it to prove your way is faster than conventional it has to be across all browsers.. Google being a search engine is probably using indexing on your data which is in a way similar to caching, modify your data between runs to see if it makes a difference..

Comment: Every time I add a new test case it has the same scale of difference, I doubt it's "google indexing" the test cases.